# What ASCII character is C-q C-E?

Tags: ascii, control-characters

I did a spurious replacement across many files that shows in Emacs as '^E', equivalently the result of [C-q](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html#Inserting-Text) C-E. What ASCII character does that correspond to, so I can undo the replacement?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control characters `^A` to `^Z` are ASCII 1 to 26; therefore `^E` is ASCII 5.

You could also ask Emacs: Type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> with point at one of those characters, and it would tell you `Char: C-e (5, #o5, #x5)`

Note that <kbd>C-q</kbd> calls `quoted-insert` which inserts the next character you type, and the next thing you typed was <kbd>C-e</kbd>.